# How get the return string from mainclass

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

DbHelper.java

```
public static String returntitle(Context context , String query) {
    DbHelper dbhelper = new DbHelper(context);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
    // Cursor cursor = null;
    String temp_title = null;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            temp_title = (cursor.getString(1));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return temp_title;
}
```

How to get the temp_title in mainclass.java

mainClass.java

```
private void gettitleform_db() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String str = "SELECT cl_title_tb_resume FROM tb_resume WHERE _id = 2 ";
    String temp2 = DbHelper.returntitle(this, str);
    System.out.println(temp2);
}
```

the above code returns an exception. whats wrong with my code. Thanks in advance

Logcat

```
11-25 13:08:52.330: W/ApplicationPackageManager(17274): getCSCPackageItemText()
11-25 13:08:52.390: D/mali_winsys(17274): new_window_surface returns 0x3000
11-25 13:08:58.145: W/ApplicationPackageManager(17274): getCSCPackageItemText()
11-25 13:08:58.160: D/AbsListView(17274): Get MotionRecognitionManager
11-25 13:08:58.175: E/CursorWindow(17274): Failed to read row 0, column 1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 1 columns.
11-25 13:08:58.175: D/AndroidRuntime(17274): Shutting down VM
11-25 13:08:58.175: W/dalvikvm(17274): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41770c08)
11-25 13:08:58.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17274): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-25 13:08:58.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17274): Process: com.absind.resumebuilder, PID: 17274
11-25 13:08:58.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17274): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.absind.resumebuilder/com.absind.resumebuilder.AddList}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
11-25 13:08:58.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2282)
11-25 13:08:58.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340)
11-25 13:08:58.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157)
11-25 13:08:58.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
11-25 13:08:58.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-25 13:08:58.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
11-25 13:08:58.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
11-25 13:08:58.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 13:08:58.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-25 13:08:58.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1259)
11-25 13:08:58.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
11-25 13:08:58.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-25 13:08:58.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17274): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
11-25 13:08:58.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):    at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
11-25 13:08:58.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):    at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
11-25 13:08:58.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
11-25 13:08:58.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):    at com.absind.resumebuilder.DbHelper.returntitle(DbHelper.java:53)
11-25 13:08:58.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):    at com.absind.resumebuilder.AddList.gettitleform_db(AddList.java:123)
11-25 13:08:58.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):    at com.absind.resumebuilder.AddList.onCreate(AddList.java:42)
11-25 13:08:58.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
11-25 13:08:58.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
11-25 13:08:58.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)
11-25 13:08:58.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: what's the exception

Comment: also why you are going through all cursor results? you could take always last result if you are interested in one only without the `do while` loop.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it. 11-25 13:08:58.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17274): at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method) 11-25 13:08:58.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17274): at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438) 11-25 13:08:58.175:  This cause the problem. please note that cursor can be null if there is no value, it is implemented in lollipop version. better to check cursor for null

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it

Answer (score 1):

Why are you sure that column index is 1?
try this:

```
temp_title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("cl_title_tb_resume"));
```

Answer (score 1):

CursorWindow has 1 row 1 column. and you are accessing column number 1. which doesn't exist. change 1 to become 0.

```
temp_title = (cursor.getString(0));
```